# как передать view в активити? intent

Tags: android, android-studio

```
TextView mess = find...(R.id...);
intent.putExtra("mess", mess);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Вместо объекта передается пустое значение, что делать?
а и.. это адаптер. я из адаптера создаю новый интент, в новом интенте подключаю фрагемент

Comment: Зачем вы передаете textview? Передайте текст, который содержится в нем

Comment: извиняюсь за некоректность вопроса. мне Фрагемент нужно изменить, после того, как я его вставил в активити. текста Фрагмента

Comment: что-то вы не то делаете... В вашем случае можно передавать `id` вашего `view`. Но это очень плохая практика

Comment: Дичь творите. Вам нужно иметь 2 отдельных текствью, а между ними в интенте передавать только текстовое значение

Comment: ну так как сделать то?